# The trait bound is not satisfied

Tags: substrate-node-template, pallet, substrate-node, pallet-staking

I am using `staking-pallet` in my runtime [here](https://github.com/XcavateBlockchain/MarketplaceMVP_Substrate/tree/staking-pallet-testing) , added all the requirements and after that I try to check dependencies using `cargo check -p node-template-runtime --release` this command but I'm getting this issue.

the trait bound `Runtime: SendTransactionTypes<pallet_election_provider_multi_phase::Call<Runtime>>` is not satisfied

[image]

The code is [here](https://github.com/XcavateBlockchain/MarketplaceMVP_Substrate/tree/staking-pallet-testing)

Someone please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error said.

You missed this.

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/ae1a608c91a5da441a0ee7c26a4d5d410713580d/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L1314-L1320

```rs
impl<C> frame_system::offchain::SendTransactionTypes<C> for Runtime
where
    RuntimeCall: From<C>,
{
    type Extrinsic = UncheckedExtrinsic;
    type OverarchingCall = RuntimeCall;
}
```

---

Why?

Because it requires the `SendTransactionTypes` trait bound.

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/ae1a608c91a5da441a0ee7c26a4d5d410713580d/frame/election-provider-multi-phase/src/lib.rs#LL575C2-L575C77

```rs
pub trait Config: frame_system::Config + SendTransactionTypes<Call<Self>> {
```